# Error terms in the Heckman models in R

Tags: r, regression, heckman

I am running a two stage model (Heckman) in R using `heckit` command from the `sampleSelection` package. In the outcome equation the DV is dichotomous, in the selection equation the DV is continuous.

I am only starting to get a grasp of this method. What I don't understand is why I get NA's for sigma and rho, see the last lines of the output below. Is this a standard thing or should I pay more attention to the dataset? Am I missing something here?

Thanks!

```
    Tobit 2 model (sample selection model)
    2-step Heckman / heckit estimation
    3073 observations (2704 censored and 369 observed)
    18 free parameters (df = 3056)
    Probit selection equation:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
    (Intercept) -1.2432522  0.0760953 -16.338  < 2e-16 ***
    x1          -0.0003995  0.0059916  -0.067    0.947    
    x2           0.0279750  0.0038107   7.341 2.70e-13 ***
    x3          -0.4127960  0.0734389  -5.621 2.07e-08 ***
    x4          -0.4093300  0.0725181  -5.645 1.81e-08 ***
    x5          -0.9499656  0.1098253  -8.650  < 2e-16 ***
    Outcome equation:
                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
    (Intercept)     0.271388   0.376571   0.721  0.47116    
    x1           -0.010837   0.003151  -3.440  0.00059 ***
    x2           -0.048475   0.051937  -0.933  0.35071    
    x3           -0.058104   0.045035  -1.290  0.19709    
    x4           -0.075902   0.094389  -0.804  0.42138    
    x5            0.017786   0.012305   1.445  0.14843    
    x6           -0.042822   0.030926  -1.385  0.16626    
    x7           -0.003184   0.010590  -0.301  0.76371    
    x8           -0.004267   0.004527  -0.943  0.34600    
    Multiple R-Squared:0.1018,  Adjusted R-Squared:0.0793
       Error terms:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
    invMillsRatio  0.04047    0.10577   0.383    0.702
    sigma          0.28354         NA      NA       NA
    rho            0.14274         NA      NA       NA
```